# How to read line by line in textearea and convert into JSON AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a textarea with some values in the following format

```
param01 : value01
param02 : value02
```

Heres why I tried

```
<div class="col-xs-4 input-container">
  <textarea id="gateway-params" ng-disabled="!edit">{{gatewayParams}}</textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.save = function() {
   for (var i = 0; $scope.gatewayParams; i++) {
      console.log(params[i]);
   }
 }
```

I want to read the textearea line by line and build a Javasript object.

Regars!.

Comment: What have you tried?  What problems are you having?  Can you show your code?

Comment: I've updated my issue :)

Comment: do you want to build one big json or an array of json?

Comment: A simple Jascript Object, not that big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//EDIT, dont add empty key/value

her is a plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/Zea3zZqaagDdO4s8pZRC?p=preview

controller side :

```
$scope.text = 'param01 : value01\nparam02 : value02\nparam03 : value03\nparam04 : value04\nparam05 : value05\nparam06 : value06\n';    

$scope.actionme = function(){   
    var lines = $scope.text.split("\n");// you get the lines
    var datas ={}; 
    for(var i in lines){
      var line = lines[i].split(":"); // you get the key / value
      // add only if the key and value not empty
      if((line.length ==2)&&(line[0].trim()!="")&&(line[1].trim()!="")){
        datas[line[0].trim()]  = line[1].trim();
      }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(datas));
}
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
   <textarea ng-model="text"> 
   </textarea>

  <button ng-click="actionme()">click</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Amazing, this fits perfectly and well explained, thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-model in your textarea you can capture your content as a string and parse it in your controller/directive.

You can use

```
.split('\n');
```

to split your string into an array of strings by new lines. I'll leave the parsing to you, but here is how you set up your object:

```
var prop = "param01";
var val = "value01";
var obj = {};
obj[prop] = val;
```